# Needing Assistance to Figure Out how to Set Up an Application/get Dependancies with a ZIP that no Longer has a Git File

Tags: npm

I have the ZIP file with the instructions telling me what I need to do but the issue is that there is no longer a GIT File for this and I wish to set it up and it requires npm.
These are the instructions from the un zipped Read Me on setting up (I also still have/kept the ZIP file).
For Development:
Clone the repo then use `npm install` to install the necessary dependencies.
Once that's done, use `npm run build` to build it, or `npm run dev` to develop it.
Open another terminal window and use `npm run start` to actually start the application.
For Building:
use `npm run dist` to package the application for distribution. This will appear in the `/dist` folder.

I just need assistance to go in the right direction as in what step I need to take to do all this and hopefully this is detailed to make it easier.

I cannot clone a repository and follow these steps exactly due to there no longer being a GIT file.